# How can I read multiple data sets after executing multiple raw queries with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have multiple queries that depends on multiple temp tables, once the execution is done, I need to return multiple datasets and mapped into a C# objects.

Here is an example

> My actual queries are much more complex and lengthy which is why I need to use temp
>   tables for the sake of performance I cut them down for the sake of simplicity

```
/** START OF SECTION 1 **/
-- Create a temp table
SELECT 
 Id
,Name
INTO #titles 
FROM Titles
WHERE column1 = 'abc';

-- Add an index on the temp table
CREATE INDEX Id #titles(Id);
/** END OF SECTION 1 **/


/** START OF SECTION 2 **/
-- This is the first result set
SELECT 
 t.*
,b.*
FROM OtherRecords as b
INNER JOIN #titles AS t ON t.Id = b.TitleId;
/** END OF SECTION 2 **/



/** START OF SECTION 3 **/
-- This is the second result set
SELECT 
 t.*
,b.*
FROM YetOtherRecords as b
INNER JOIN #titles AS t ON t.Id = b.TitleId;
/** END OF SECTION 3 **/

DROP TABLE #titles;
```

As you can see, I am executing multiple queries, then the end result are two data sets that I need to map to my C# models.

I tried to execute the above queries "separated by section" into multiple Entity-Framework commands like so

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Queries from section 1 above");
var records = context.Database.SqlQuery<OtherRecord>("Queries from section 2 above").ToList();
var otherRecords = context.Database.SqlQuery<YetOtherRecord>("Queries from section 3 above").ToList();
```

However that does not work because each command issues a new connection to the database so the temp table will only be available for the first query (i.e `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Queries from section 1 above")`.)

How can run all the queries above yet generate the two data sets without having to create the temp table on each call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learning from [Microsoft's example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj691402(v=vs.113).aspx)

You'll need to create a `DbDataReader` and read the records from it, because that allows you to read the rows from a result set and then move to subsequent result sets by calling `NextResult()`. There will be a result set for each `SELECT` in your stored procedure, even if a result set is empty.

Then you'll cast the context as `IObjectContextAdapter` and call `IObjectContextAdapter.ObjectContext.Translate<TEntity>` to create an `ObjectResult<TEntity>` containing the objects created from each row. For it to do this mapping the column names returned must match the properties of the class it's populating.

(The Microsoft example doesn't dispose of its IDisposables. Maybe there's a reason.)

```
// Just some class with two lists to contain the results.
var result = new ContainsTheResults();

using (var db = new YourDbContext())
{
    using (var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[YourProcedureName]";
        try
        {
            db.Database.Connection.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {

                // Translate the rows in the current result set to a collection of objects
                using (var otherRecords = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
                    .ObjectContext
                    .Translate<OtherRecord>(reader, "OtherRecords", MergeOption.AppendOnly))
                {
                    result.OtherRecords = otherRecords.ToList();
                }

                // Go to the next result and read those
                reader.NextResult();
                using (var yetOtherRecords = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
                    .ObjectContext
                    .Translate<YetOtherRecord>(reader, "YetOtherRecords", MergeOption.AppendOnly))
                {
                    result.YetOtherRecords = yetOtherRecords.ToList();
                }                     
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            db.Database.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
}

return result;
```